# Why doesn't QLineEdit Style change when focused?

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I'm developing a GUI using Qt and its stylesheets. On the main window stylesheet I've put the following style:

```
QLineEdit:focus {
    border: 2px solid #006080;
}
```

But when I use it the style doesn't really change as I expected. However, if I put the same stylesheet directly on the desired component, it works like magic! But well, it's not really a good idea to put stylesheets on every single LineEdit I may want (which would greatly increase the amount of work needed to add new components or change the stylesheet), neither reapplying the stylesheet by adding code lines such as `setStyleSheet(styleSheet())`.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 9):

Odd, it works as desired on my copy of Qt using QLineEdit:focus using

```
QLineEdit:focus
{
    border: 2px solid #006080;
}
```

Are you sure you do not have a child style somewhere farther down the line overruling this? As it is on the MainWindow it will be the first thing to be overruled.

A potential work-around is to use an event filter:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->lineEdit->installEventFilter( this );
    ui->lineEdit_2->installEventFilter( this );
}

...

bool MainWindow::eventFilter( QObject *object, QEvent *event )
{
    QLineEdit* edit = qobject_cast< QLineEdit* >( object );

    if( edit != NULL )
    {
        if( event->type( ) == QEvent::FocusIn )
        {
            edit->setStyleSheet( QString( "border: 10px solid #000000;" ) );
        }
        else if( event->type( ) == QEvent::FocusOut )
        {
            edit->setStyleSheet( QString( "border: 1px solid #000000;" ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Of course QStyleSheets are simply QStrings so you can have pre-defined styles stored away for use.

Answer (score 2):

You can set focus styles programmatically if needed like this:

```
QString styleSheet = "QLineEdit { border: 1px solid; border-color:#dcdcdc; border-radius: 4px;} QLineEdit:focus{border:1px solid gray;}";

yourFancyEdit->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
```