# How to change the color of line edit once a user selects it in Qt desginer

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5, qlineedit

I am working on `pyqt5` project and building the UI layout in `qt designer`. Below is the login screen which has two line edits in it for username and password:

[image]

I want to update the border color of the line edit to color of the button once a user starts typing. So that it can look like below:

[image]

How can I do it in qt designer. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you can do it directly from Qt Designer but as an alternative you could use **QLineEdit signals**. For example you can change the stylesheet when **textEdited** is emitted and change it back when **editingFinished** is emitted

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684394/why-doesnt-qlineedit-style-change-when-focused help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Qt Widget Designer. Because there is no support. But with Qt Quick Designer (qml) you can do it by using the State Machine.

So for your solution, I suggest you use directly a signal on QLineEdit and change the stylesheet using code on the slot.